# Is there anyway to automate actions with this page with headless selenium firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox-marionette

I was running scripts (automated payments) for the previous version of [this portal](https://ibank.nbg.gr/identity/login?ReturnUrl=https:%2F%2Fibank.nbg.gr%2Fidentity%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3D48423927-4F90-46A4-9F41-63A0B3114A92%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fibank.nbg.gr%252Fweb%252F%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520role%2520ibank_profile%2520ibank-cards-api-v1%2520ibank-loans-api-v1%2520ibank-profile-api-v1%2520ibank-go4more-api-v1%2520ibank-billpayments-api-v1%2520ibank-accounts-api-v1%2520ibank-proxy-api-v1%26state%3DOpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%253D3tP2ICLlQXSz7NC-pgLykBLQSVszlMygBdTcCup0TA-ySLABDDNKm9wC_IuN4PJe0gSdNCVrXDI1TskntUbdHl170X2d1AtIYYll4psfjgogqdnii7uGFeYY9DhAU5419o5lU_bmfm1L3QwzgJd78MtMooMTgF1Ancj6k8btGg7hGiYiKJF09rxhIE_BAni6rAkNA_tyvvHJhoz0l6C5Nw%26nonce%3D637350760833021182.MTQxMmQyYmItZDc2Zi00NmZiLTlmM2MtY2Q2YTAxY2RiN2RiN2Y5NDQyZjItYjZkOS00ODlhLTg1ODItNDk0YTNmZGNiNjFm%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NET451%26x-client-ver%3D5.2.1.0)

However, they changed the portal, and now whenever I try to go for example to the next screen with my script the page says that something went wrong. I assume it is because their website realizes that I run headless Mozilla and declines my query. Is there any way to bypass this? it saves me a lot of time to make payments automatically. I run the script with python selenium Mozilla. This is an example of the code

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    #
    import datetime
    import time
    import numpy as np
    import openpyxl
    import pyautogui
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
    import keyboard
    import os
    import xlrd
    import shutil
    
    firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
    
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
        
    
    driver.get('https://ibank.nbg.gr/identity/login?ReturnUrl=https:%2F%2Fibank.nbg.gr%2Fidentity%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3D48423927-4F90-46A4-9F41-63A0B3114A92%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fibank.nbg.gr%252Fweb%252F%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520role%2520ibank_profile%2520ibank-cards-api-v1%2520ibank-loans-api-v1%2520ibank-profile-api-v1%2520ibank-go4more-api-v1%2520ibank-billpayments-api-v1%2520ibank-accounts-api-v1%2520ibank-proxy-api-v1%26state%3DOpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%253D3tP2ICLlQXSz7NC-pgLykBLQSVszlMygBdTcCup0TA-ySLABDDNKm9wC_IuN4PJe0gSdNCVrXDI1TskntUbdHl170X2d1AtIYYll4psfjgogqdnii7uGFeYY9DhAU5419o5lU_bmfm1L3QwzgJd78MtMooMTgF1Ancj6k8btGg7hGiYiKJF09rxhIE_BAni6rAkNA_tyvvHJhoz0l6C5Nw%26nonce%3D637350760833021182.MTQxMmQyYmItZDc2Zi00NmZiLTlmM2MtY2Q2YTAxY2RiN2RiN2Y5NDQyZjItYjZkOS00ODlhLTg1ODItNDk0YTNmZGNiNjFm%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NET451%26x-client-ver%3D5.2.1.0')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/index-page/div/login/div/div[1]/sign-in/sign-in-form/div/div/div/div[1]/div/input').send_keys(12345678)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/index-page/div/login/div/div[1]/sign-in/sign-in-form/div/div/div/div[2]/spinner/button').click()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried to fix the issue? Stackoverflow is a question / answer website, not a place to ask people to fix their code

Comment: The code would work in another website which would allow headless mode. The particular element which is mentioned in the code for example is clickable  with manual exploration of the website. But when i try to run my script with python and do the same operations automated it shows my an error message. I am just asking for help bypassing this problem not someone fixing my entire code.